# How to fix the image position in UIImageView while editing the image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on some image distortion project, Where I need to implement various distortion effects on image. The issue which I am facing is, some of the image get rotated when I do distortion on that.

It happens only with some `images`. While other `images` works perfectly. So is there any way to fix the position of `image` like portrait in `UIImageView`.

Please provide any solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved my issue. Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670682/iphone-preventing-an-image-to-rotate-into-its-uiimageview)

```
UIImage* rotatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
myImageView.image = rotatedImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are thes UIImage objects? If so then check the orientation property. Depending on where your original image data comes from the UIImage orientation may be influenced by the orientation setting of related EXIF tags.